# Widgets and painter is getting overlayed by QVideoWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a VideoWidget that is occupies the whole window. And i would like to have to have a QPushButton and some text via Qpainter that overlays on top of the video.

What is happening though is the button and the text is the one being overlayed by the VideoWidget. The button is there i can even click it, i just cant see it

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    video = new QVideoWidget(this);
    video->setGeometry(0,0,this->width(),this->height());
    video->show();

    this->repaint();

    optionsButton = new QPushButton(this);
    optionsButton->setText("O");
    optionsButton->setGeometry(20,20,40,40);
    optionsButton->show();

    connect(optionsButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(optionsButtonClicked()));

    player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    audio = new QAudioOutput(this);

    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::errorChanged,this,&MainWindow::mediaPlayerDebugError);
    connect(player,&QMediaPlayer::mediaStatusChanged,this,&MainWindow::mediaPlayerDebugStatus);


    player->setAudioOutput(audio);
    player->setVideoOutput(video);
    player->setSource(QUrl("rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.199:554/mpeg4/ch0/main/av_stream"));

    player->play();

}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
    painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Qt");
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what i see

[image]

and a screenshot without the VideoWidget

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't do this with `QVideoWidget`: the underlying video system draws directly to the window bypassing `Qt`'s paint engine.  Instead you might want to look at [`QGraphicsVideoItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsvideoitem.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71777390/make-qgraphicsvideoitem-fill-qwidget).

Comment: Wanted to say that I got exact same problem, thank you for asking

Answer (score 1):

Use QVideoProbe [doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#details) to capture frames and process them before they're displayed. Drawing the button and text on each frame in the slot used to capture the video frames will work. You might need to actually draw/paint your own button and handle mouse events inside the button area yourself.

*From the Qt documentation:*

```
QVideoProbe *probe = new QVideoProbe;

connect(probe,SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)),this,SLOT(processFrame(QVideoFrame)));
```